# How to store scaling parameters for later use - SCALE - R

Tags: r

I am using the scale function in R and I want to save the used parameters in another dataset.

```
df$Monto_Trx_RECEP<-scale(df$Monto_Trx_RECEP,center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
```

Comment: What do you mean, to store scaling parameters? See if `attributes(df$Monto_Trx_RECEP)` answer your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.